# How to handle array to find a specific string using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, disk

I want to match a string in my XML file with the physical disk result.
I tried this way, but it always goes to raid process even the name of the physical disk exists in the XML list.

This is what my XML list looks like, it is an array.
(I take only some part of XML that I needed)

```
    ....
    <Name>
        <type> TOSHIBA 0012 </type>
        <type> INTEL MEMORY</type>
        <type> SATA DISK </type>
    </Name>
    ....
TOSHIBA 0012
INTEL MEMORY
SATA DISK

function raidprocess
{
     Write-Host "raid process"
     break
}

function optaneprocess
{
     Write-Host "optane process"
     break
}

[xml]$ConfigFile = Get-Content -Path .\file.xml
$Name = $ConfigFile.Name.type

foreach ($type in $Name)
{
     $DP = Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object FriendlyName, Size | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like "*$type *"}
     
     if (!($DP))
     {
          Write-Host "Raid"
          raidprocess
     }
     else {

          Write-Host "Optane"
          optaneprocess
     }
}
```

anyone can help me, please. Thank you

Comment: Is this an exact copy from the original XML file or did you manually type this in the post? Some, but not all items have trailing and leading spaces.. Are you sure these should be the FriendlyName and not lets say `Model` ? Remove the space in `"*$type *"` --> `$_.FriendlyName -like "*$type*"`

Answer (score 0):

```
@"
<Name>
    <type> TOSHIBA 0012 </type>
    <type> INTEL MEMORY</type>
    <type> SATA DISK </type>
</Name>
"@ | out-file d:\tmp\input.xml

# the code above to create an example file

[xml]$doc = Get-Content d:\tmp\input.xml
$values = $doc.Name.type

(Get-PhysicalDisk).FriendlyName | ForEach-Object {
    if ($values -contains $_) {
        #action
    }
    else 
    {
        #action
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it still not working. it always return the result that the $values not contain of the physicaldisk friendlyname.

Comment: post output of this [xml]$doc = Get-Content d:\tmp\input.xml;
 ($doc.Name.type).Trim()

Comment: The output `TOSHIBA 0012 
INTEL MEMORY
SATA DISK ` it's an array type.

Comment: Let's try to exclude .trim()

Comment: @ Алексей Семенов  the same thing, still the same result

Comment: Post output of this (Get-PhysicalDisk).FriendlyName | ForEach-Object {
   "[{0}]" -f $_
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226503/discussion-between---and-sbr).